# Is it ok to add more detail to a question?

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions

I ran into an issue related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872547/warning-in-custom-map-annotations-iphone), where if more detail was given in both the answer and the question, I would've been more informed of the actual problem, and solution.  I've added the detail of the answer as my own answer, but I'm not sure what to do with the additional detail to the question.  Details that I'm wanting to add are:

- The fact that the error happens during the adding of custom annotations to a map.
- Possibly adding some more detailed debugging techniques/printout I used.
- I might even added some "dummy code" to the question to show a typical situation.

While this is a specific question that I have run into, I'm wondering on a more global basis whether it's alright for a user to add more detail to another person's question?

Comment: IMHO Unless you're 100% convinced that the error you're having was exactly the same as the OP its probably better to Ask a new question and answer it yourself.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter I'm scared of it being closed as a duplicate since the answer is still mainly the same.

Comment: I don't think duplicates are supposed to work that way. The same answer can apply to multiple questions without the questions being duplicates. Also, and this is the reason why you might want to raise a separate question,  the same error  message can be caused by more than one problem.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicates are something to be wary of on most SE sites.

If you have done considerable research on the subject, *including* the possible duplicate and you still face your problem.  The question is then **can you make your question seem different enough on its own?**

It also helps to cite **every** step you have taken to solve your problem so that other users can follow your predicament and explain to them *why* you believe this is *not* a duplicate of *Question X*.

If you cannot easily do this then your other option is to pop into that site's [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com) or even invite the asker of the original question to a chatroom and get a discussion going that way (you are able to do this from their chat profile), and find out if their issue is actually resolved/other steps they may have taken that are not on the site.

Comment: What do duplicates have to do with adding more detail to the question?

Comment: @RobertHarvey in reference to what he said about posting a duplicate question or editing in his part of the question.